# In commutative ring, flat is equivalent to locally free

Tags: commutative-algebra

In wikipedia https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_module , particularly Case of commutative rings, they say that

"In a commutative ring, a finitely generated module is flat if and only if it is locally free, i.e. $M_P$ is free for all prime ideals"

In Atiyah anf MacDonald's commutative algebra, they proved that

"In a commutative ring, a finitely generated module is flat if and only if it is locally flat, i.e. $M_P$ is flat for all prime ideals"

So does it mean "$M_P$ is free iff $M_P$ is flat"? How? $R_P$ is only local while we need it to be also Noetherian for the statement to be true?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I also don't know how to remove the Noetherian hypothesis, so I suspect the first statement is false with no Noetherian hypotheses.

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33522/flatness-and-local-freeness .